# java web service axis2+rampart+sandesha2 Create Sequence not signed

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

I am required to add WS-Addressing, WS-Security, and WS-Reliablity to a legacy java web service that runs on Apache Axis2.

I found out that Axis2 comes with WS-Addressing support. Then I installed Apache Rampart (v1.6.2, for WS-Security) and Apache Sandesha2 (v1.6.2, for WS-Reliable Messaging) on top of Axis2 (v1.6.2; running on Apache Tomcat (v1.7.0_30)).

After doing some research, I added my policies to my services META-INF/services.xml file. (The policy requires https and the header to be signed.) I can deploy the service to Tomcat without any exceptions. I can see the service using the axis2 url (http://localhost:8080/axis2).

Now I am attempting to write a java client for this service. I used the axis2 'wsdl2java' code generator to create the stubs. My test client service is able to call the service. However, on the server side, I get an exception "AxisFault : Message is not signed" (required by policy). The server logs also show the 'CreateSequence' message (part of WS-Reliable Messaging) is not signed.

Does anyone have insight on how to sign the 'CreateSequence' message? Also, it would be helpful to have a link to a sample client/service that uses Axis2, Rampart, and Sandesha2. Thanks in advance.